# dropdown submenu links cant change tabs-pane when they are clicked second time

Tags: html, css, dropdown

```css
dropdown-submenu
{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover>a, .dropdown-submenu:focus>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#08c,#0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#08c),to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#08c,#0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#08c,#0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#08c,#0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc',endColorstr='#ff0077b3',GradientType=0);
}
```

NEW TAB

```
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#dp_1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">DATA POOL</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="drp1">
      <li><a href="#dp_1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_2"  data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_3"  data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_4"  data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_5"  data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

when i click on the links of dropdwn submenu the links works fine one first click but when i click on the links second time it does not work and cant change tab-pane.  Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Add css code too for more clarification.

Comment: so the problem is the dropdown is not working properly? Are you using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: @LavyaR Yeah i should add css

Comment: @SahilDhir yeah i have added bootstrap too.

Comment: @SahilDhir Is it possible that a link works for the first time but not on second or more time?

Comment: there is a problem in your code. I am just answering

Comment: @LavyaR i have just added the css please check it

Comment: @LavyaR   
this is my actual problem...please see the link w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFAFJ165H7B

Comment: @SahilDhir  
this is my actual problem...please see the link w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFAFJ165H7B

Comment: so you want something just like this :P ??

Comment: @SahilDhir have you seen that link?

Comment: @LavyaR have you seen that link?

Comment: @CodingFriend Yes. I am working on it.

Comment: @LavyaR Yeah Please find the solution.

Comment: @CodingFriend I have put the solution. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @CodingFriend I think you have got your answer.. But do check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works for you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
   $(this).next('ul').toggle();
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
var arr= $(this).next('ul')[0].children;
var array = $.map(arr, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
array.forEach(function(){
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
});
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...! You have no idea how much i was stuck due to this problem. You are truly a genius...thank you so much....

Comment: @LavyaR nice answer :)  Upvote..  But bootstrap also gives its method to solve the problem.. Do check my answer :)

Comment: @SahilDhir Will you please tell me shortly what was the problem in my code...and what thing you have done to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

> Fixture Explanation=

First of all i dint find the script I  made it with logic . Secondly after deeply studying your code I found out what you wanted to achieve.. The problem in the code was that in multi- dropdown approach the tab clicks get confused and the active class was added to all the list  itemsthat initialize the tabs which cause the clicks to block the second time we click on them.. So to fix this I used a method of bootstrap which will fix the things.Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').not(this).parent().removeClass('active');

      });
       });
```

**This code basically removes class on any other list item and add class to the current click element only thus making the tabs to work perfectly .**

> Below id thw working snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').not(this).parent().removeClass('active');

      });
       });
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -6px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
           
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
            display: block;
            content: " ";
            float: right;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
            border-left-color: #ccc;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
            border-left-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
            float: none;
        }
        
        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
            left: -100%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Web <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
      <li><a href="#asad1">jQuedasdsadry</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Open </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu " id="MyTab">
          <li><a href="#dp_1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_2"  data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_3"  data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_4"  data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dp_5"  data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>

        </ul>


      </li>


    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane" id="dp_1">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Tab content 1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="dp_2">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Tab content 2
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="dp_3">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Tab content 3
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="dp_4">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Tab content 4
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="dp_5">
    <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Tab content 5
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i have changes collapse to dropdown still not working

Comment: this is my actual problem...please see the link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFAFJ165H7B

Comment: @CodingFriend my answer is very simple and one liner script

Comment: Please tell me ! Where do i find your one liner script?

Comment: You are a genius bro !!! please share you email id...or send me a message on mine i.e coolwebstar123@gmail.com

Comment: Will you please tell me shortly what was the problem in my code...and what thing you have done to solve it ?

Comment: I will be available shortly and explain you the answer.. please upvote and accept this answer if you find it best 

Comment: @CodingFriend First of all i dint find the script I  made it with logic . Secondaly after deeply studing your code i found out what you wanted to achieve.. The problem in the code was that in multi- dropdown approach the tab clicks get confused and the active class was added to the list that initialize he tabs which cause the clicks to block the second time we click o them.. So to fix this I used a method of bootstrap which will fix the things..

Comment: @CodingFriend Also updated my answer with explanation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143850/discussion-between-sahil-dhir-and-codingfriend).

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Initialize dropdown toggle , it will work. 
Call above function.